# How to prove a graph is a manifold?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $f$ be a $C^k$ map defined in an open set $U\in \mathbb R^n$, I'm trying to prove this is a manifold. I couldn't find a parametrization. I've tried $\varphi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=(x_1,\ldots,x_n,f(x_1,\ldots,x_n))$, but I couldn't prove this is an homeomorphism. I need help here.

Comment: Where do you get stuck in showing that $\phi$ is a homeomorphism?

Comment: @littleO If $f$ is not $1-1$, then $\varphi$ isn't $1-1$ either

Comment: Actually, $\phi$ is $1-1$ even if $f$ is not $1-1$.  I bet you could prove that.  You could start by supposing that $\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \phi(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$.

Comment: @littleO yes, you're right, I've just proved. It's easy. To prove the onto part, can I restrict the image of $\varphi$ to be only the graph of $f$?

Comment: I think you can show that $\phi$ is onto by using the definition of the "graph" of a function.  Suppose that a point $p$ belongs to the graph of $f$.  By the definition of the graph of a function, $p$ has the form $p = \ldots$

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You've got the right parameterization. It's certainly a 1-1 map (why?), and certainly onto (why?), and certainly continuous (why?), and indeed, $C^k$ (why? What's the derivative matrix at $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ look like?).

Hint:
The only possible remaining part is finding an inverse and proving that the inverse is nice as well. So: here's the inverse. Let $K$ denote the graph of $f$.

$$
p: K \to \Bbb R^n : (x_1, \ldots, x_n, u_{n+1}, \ldots, u_k) \mapsto  (x_1, \ldots, x_n).
$$

Can you explain why $p$ is continuous, 1-1 (on $K$), and $C^k$?

Comment: Can I say $\varphi$ is continuous because $\pi_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=x_i$ and $f$ are continuous? can I apply the same argument to prove $\varphi$ is a $C^k$ map?

Comment: Yes, $\phi$ is continuous because each component of $\phi$ is continuous. The same kind of argument works for $C^k$.

Comment: John, how would one prove that the graph is an open set?

Comment: Well, it's the preimage of an open set (namely $U$) under a continuous map (namely $p$). Of course, that only makes $K$ open **in $K$**. Then again, that's the only notion that makes sense. In general it's *not* open in $\Bbb R^n$; look at the graph of $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R : x \mapsto 0$ in $\Bbb R^2$: the graph is a horizontal line; its complement is the union of two open halfspaces in $\Bbb R^2$, hence open, so the graph is (as a subset of $\Bbb R^2$)  closed. It can't be both closed **and** open, because it's not a component of $\Bbb R^2$. Hence it's not open (as a subset of the plane).